# Caching in Yii framework

Tags: yii

For caching the country list for used in drop list by using api, which is the best way or which cache is best in Yii framework? When we can cache this country list in cache?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview) and [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.0/en/caching.data)

Comment: You should be more specific if you want a detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

I will provide you with a few links to help out, and also an example.  Firstly, you should check out
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data to understand caching in yii.

I am using APC Caching, which involves installing the APC PHP extension, and configuring your config/main.php 
There is an article on how to do this here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/312/getting-the-most-out-of-apc-for-yii/

Next, in order to cache a country list, you could do the following

```
$tableName  =  CountryName::model()->tableName();
$dependencySql ='select max('.$tableName.'.update_time)  from '.$tableName;

$dependency = new CDbCacheDependency($dependencySql);

$myModelSql= 'select name from '. $tablename;

$allCountries= CountryName::model()->cache(1000, $dependency)->findAllBySql($myModelSql);
```

If $allCountries hasn't been updated in the last 1000 seconds, Yii will retrieve from cache instead of hitting the db.

Hope this helps